# Mk1 Ford Focus green residue on reverse light bulb

Tags: electrical, reverse-lights

When changing my reversing light bulb I noticed green liquid on the bottom of the old one. The new bulb won't work at all. Do you think I just need to clean the socket out (and if so, do I use water?) Or is it possibly a fuse issue? Or maybe it needs rewiring? I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If the green residue you mention is on the bulb & its housing contacts then this is just oxidisation caused by moisture reacting with the bulb & socket materials. If it's not too bad you can clean it off.. Firstly though make sure the lights are switched OFF, OR DISCONNECT THE BULBS POWER CONNECTIONS FIRST so its not live, then use some IPA (isopropyl alcohol) or warm water if that's all you have, and a use a small wire brush or some sandpaper etc to remove the oxidisation/corrosion.
Once the contacts are clean use some switch cleaner or contact grease on the sockets surfaces to help prevent further issue, a TINY smear off copper grease etc can also be used to protect the surfaces. Assuming the connection is then ok and there are no other issues your bulb should work again.